# Searching through lines without lower case

Tags: unix

I'm looking to search through a line where I must indicate the 3rd and 4th characters should not be lowercase. This is what I have so far however, I'm not sure how to indicate both characters in one line of code.

```
    ls grep | $...[!a-z].$....[!a-z]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
grep -e '^..[^a-z][^a-z].*$' test.txt
```

test.txt:

```
abaXYom
abCdef
ghIJkl
lalalolo papa
234234234
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
ghIJkl
234234234
```

Comment: The `.*` isn't really necessary.  The `^` is a metacharacter indicating start of line.  The 2 dots represent characters 1 and 2; any character is allowed.  The `[^a-z]` units represent characters 3 and 4, therefore, and each says 'anything but lower case.  The `.*` at the end means anything, but you don't need to explicitly match that. The test strings should arguably include `abCdef` and `ghIJkl`, with the expected output including the second line.

Comment: Thanks. It worked out! I see that you replaced the 3rd and 4th dots.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right, the reason I added the `.*` was that I intended to also add the `$` at the end of the expression, but forgot to do so (I'm sloppy). And you're also right about the fact that my "unit-test" doesn't include all the relevant cases (I'm lazy too)  :) fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I did the following and it worked for me.

`ls | grep -e '^..[^a-z][^a-z].*$'`

**Example:**

```
mkdir abcD abcd abcde abCD ABCD ABcd abCDe
ls | grep -e '^..[^a-z][^a-z].*$'
```

When I executed the above commands, I go the following output:

```
$ ls | grep -e '^..[^a-z][^a-z].*$'
ABCD
abCD
abCDe
$
```

You are trying to restrict lower case using `[!a-z]`. You should use `[^a-z]` for this purpose.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @alfasin: yeah.. I started writing the answer and some one came by my desk before I could post the answer. So, got late :)